# Issue with Jackson's polymorphic serialization of AtomicLong

Tags: jackson

I need to do a [polymorphic-serialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) of a Java class containing an `AtomicLong` is its tree.

I initialize ObjectMapper of *Jackson 2.9.2* as follows

```
private final static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()///
    .findAndRegisterModules()//
    .enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)//
    .setDefaultPrettyPrinter(new MinimalPrettyPrinter())//
    .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)//
    .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES)//
    .disable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)//
    .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
```

Then I serialize my class into JSON, for which I am showing the culprit **fragment**

```
"progress":{"com.acme.SimpleProgressObject":{"current":0,"total":null,"status":null,"error":null,"innerProgress":null}}
```

Note `current` equals to plain 0. Class is made of

```
public class SimpleProgressObject implements AsyncProgress, AsyncProgressSupplier, Serializable
{
    private final AtomicLong current = new AtomicLong(0);
    private AtomicLong total;
    private String status;
    private Throwable error;
    private SimpleProgressObject innerProgress;
}
```

When I deserialize this stuff from its container, I get the following error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected START_OBJECT: need JSON Object to contain As.WRAPPER_OBJECT type information for class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
 at [Source: [truncated]; line: 1, column: 145] (through reference chain: ProcessExecutionContext["progress"]->SimpleProgressObject["current"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1498)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportWrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1273)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:100)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:52)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:121)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:52)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:121)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:52)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2992)
```

I suppose that the correct JSON could have been (beautified)

```
{
   "progress":{
      "com.acmeSimpleProgressObject":{
         "current":{
            "java.util.concurrent.AtomicLong":0
         },
         "total":null,
         "status":null,
         "error":null,
         "innerProgress":null
      }
   }
}
```

Question is: is my code wrong or is this an issue with Jackson itself? I refrained from opening an issue on Github in doubt

Edit 1: same happens changing `.enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY)//`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I did not post the getters/setters, which help understand the culprit

```
@Override
public Long getCurrent()
{
    if (current == null)
        return null;
    return current.longValue();
}

@Override
public Long getTotal()
{
    if (total == null)
        return null;
    return total.longValue();
}

@Override
public void setTotal(Long total)
{
    if (total == null)
        this.total = null;
    else
        this.total = new AtomicLong(total);
}

@Override
public String getStatus()
{
    return status;
}

@Override
public void setStatus(String status)
{
    this.status = status;
}

@Override
public Throwable getError()
{
    return error;
}
```

Since I have a getter for `current` that returns `Long`, Jackson uses it to serialize it to a basic type, without wrapping. It's not in fact a getter, but a utility method to honour an interface contract.

However, when deserialzing, Jackson is capable of setting final fields via reflection, but finds a primitive value in the payload. The latter is correct behaviour, but is caused by my non-canonical getter.

Solution in my case was to add a parameterized private constructor accepting `@JsonSetter("current") Long current`

I was wishing to close this question immediately as being off topic because it is very specific to my case, but after all the effort finding the cause I ask the community to decide on the life of this question.